# Elasticsearch to filter strings based on lists of filters (Nest)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a list with some 100'000 names. I would like to filter the list based on the filters in the class below, to then get a random name from the result.

This is already working with some linq-satements, but it gets slower as the filter lists grow.

```
export class UserState{
    constructor(
        public StartsWithFilters: string[], //exclude all names starting with
        public EndsWithFilters: string[], //exclude all names containing
        public ContainsFilters: string[], //exclude all names ending with
        public EqualsFilters: string[], //exclude all names equal to
        public CurrentName : string //the random name from the filtered list
    ){
        this.SelectedNames = [];
    }
}
```

All the names are indexed in /names and the type looks like this:

```
public class Name{
    public string NameText{get;set;}
}
```

So i was thinking of using elastic search to do this for me.

Since i am an Elasticsearch n00b, i would like your help with figuring out if this is a good use case for Elasticsearch, or if i should use something else. If it is a good use case, please suggest a query to to point me in the right direction.

I am using C# and Nest.

Thank you!

Comment: This can be easily achieved with Elasticsearch. For 100,000 names, you probably don't even need to analyze the inputs in any specific way, `wildcard`, `regexp` and `prefix` queries are probably fast enough. For great performance you would want to analyze at index time.

Comment: Sounds good. I will check out wildcard, regexp and prefix queries along with analyzing at index time. Will update with an answer once i have a solution. Cheers.